# Enumerate all possible decisions rules

Tags: matlab, matrix, decision-tree, markov-chains, bayesian-networks

I have `m` input variables `I_1, ..., I_m` to a decision. Each variable may have `n` possible values. The decision outcome `D` is binary.

A decision rule R is a mapping from set `D x I_1 x ... x I_m` onto the set `{0, 1}` such that for any `(i_1, ..., i_m) in I_1 x ... x I_m` it holds that `1 = sum_(d in D) R(d, i_1, ..., i_m)`. That is: for any combination of input values only one decision is possible.

For example without any input variable you have two decision rules:

```
D   R1   R2
a    0    1
b    1    0
```

That is the rule `R1` selects decision `b` while `R2` selects `a`.

With one binary input variable `I` you have four possible decision rules:

```
I   D   R1   R2   R3   R4
0   a    0    0    1    1
0   b    1    1    0    0
1   a    0    1    0    1
1   b    1    0    1    0
```

That is the decision rule `R2` selects `b` if input is `0` and it selects `a` if input is `1`.

With two binary input variables `I` and `K` you have 16 possible decision rules

```
I    K    D    R1   R2   R3   R4   R5   R6   R7   R8   R9   R10  R11  R12  R13  R14  R15  R16
0    0    a    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
0    0    b    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1    0    a    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1
1    0    b    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
0    1    a    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1
0    1    b    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    1    0    0
1    1    a    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
1    1    b    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0
```

My question how can I enumerate all possible decision rules for an arbitrary set of input variables?

Disclaimer: This is part of a homework. However the homework is restricted to the case with one binary input variable such that one can simply enumerate all four cases. I passed this part of my homework - actually an enumeration is not necessary at all - but I am interested in a general solution in matlab.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "enumerate all possible decision rules"? Do you mean getting the total number possible combinations such as "16 possible decision rules"?

Comment: @Cebri yes I would like to have all 16 instances D1 to D16, that is I need 16 vectors. Keep in mind that for any combination of input variables only one decision is possible. For the example above and `I == 0` Dx can either be a or b not both and not nothing.

Comment: Understood. By the way, please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that with two binary input variables there are 8 possible decision rules not 16.

Comment: @Cebri I added all 16 decision rules D1 ... D16. You habe 8 combinations of different combinations of [I1, I2, D] (`2^3`) but you have 16 decision rules (`2^(2^2`)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I enumerate all possible decision rules for an
>   arbitrary set of input variables?

First by analyzing and understanding the **repetitive patterns** that are visible when we write down the binary [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the decision rules (R), based on the number (`n`) of input variables (V). And then **building a set functions** that generate these permutations automatically and display a table with the results like you would do it by hand.

In terms of code, there are many different valid approaches to solve this problem, but from my point of view, I think that working with a matrix of logicals is a good way to do it. I will call this matrix (`M`). This matrix has three parts (like the tables in your description):

1. Left: `n` columns for the input variables (V)
2. Center: `1` column for the decision (D)
3. Right: `2^(2^n)` columns for the decision rules (R)

And since your problem has two decisions (A and B), we can treate them as logical values too:

- A = `0`
- B = `1`

Note: I chose this values for A and B, and not the opposite ones, because it allows us to generate the binary permutations (which I will call "*states*") of the input variables (V) and the decision (D) using natural binary count.

For `n = 0`, `M` looks like:

```
0   0   1
1   1   0
```

For `n = 1`, `M` looks like:

```
0   0   0   0   1   1
0   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   1
1   1   1   0   1   0
```

For `n = 2`, `M` looks like:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
```

And the size of `M` grows up pretty quickly as you mentioned:

- Rows ("*states*") grow at a rate of `2^(n + 1)`
- Columns grow at a rate of `(n + 1) + 2^(2^n)`: `n` columns for input variables + `1` column for decision (D) + `2^(2^n)` columns for decision rules (R).

From the previous matrices we can hardly tell apart any repetitive patterns, but if we use colors we can clearly see some patterns in the decision rules (R) region:

For `n = 0`:

[image: M for n = 0]

For `n = 1`:

[image: M for n = 1]

For `n = 2`:

[image: M for n = 2]

We can see that there are row-wise copies of the same "*unit pattern*" (boxed digits). Each "*unit pattern*" is `2` rows wide and `2^(2^n)/k` columns wide (where `k` is the number of repetitions of a pattern for every two rows). The first pattern in `M` is always a single copy (`k = 1`), and `k` duplicates every 2 rows.

We will use all this information to create a set of functions that will allow us to enumerate all the possible decision rules through the use of a [`table`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) that I will call (`T`).

---

I wrote a function called `CalcParams` which calculates all the necessary parameters of the problem (such as number of rows and columns of `M`, etc.) based on `n`:

```
function[a, b, c, d, e] = CalcParams(n)
% Calculate necessary parameters.
% Inputs:
% n - number of input variables.

% Number of states (rows).
a = 2^(n + 1);
% Number of decision rules (R) (decision rules columns).
b = 2^(2^n);
% Column index of first decision rule (R1).
c = n + 2;
% Number of columns of input variables (V) and decision (D).
d = n + 1;
% Total number of columns.
e = d + b;
end
```

---

Then I wrote a function called `ValidDecRules` which given `n` and `M`, checks if the input decision rules meet the requirement:

> For any combination of input variables only one decision is possible.

If the decision rules meet the requirement the function returns `1` and displays the message `VALID decision rules`, otherwise the function returns `0` and displays the message `INVALID decision rules`.

```
function[val] = ValidDecRules(n, M)
% This function checks if the input decision rules meet the requirement:
% For any combination of input variables only one decision is possible.
% Inputs:
% n - number of input variables.
% M - binary matrix.

% Calculate necessary parameters.
[~, ~, c, ~, e] = CalcParams(n);

% Invalid decision rules by default.
val = 0;
% Extract odd rows from decision rules (R).
M_odd = M(1:2:end, c:e);
% Extract even rows from decision rules (R).
M_even = M(2:2:end, c:e);

% Check that all elements of the odd rows are different than the elements
% of the even rows.
if(all(all(M_odd ~= M_even, 1), 2))
    % Valid decision rules.
    val = 1;
    disp('VALID decision rules');
else
    % Invalid decision rules.
    disp('INVALID decision rules');
end

end
```

---

Then I wrote a function called `GenM` which generates the binary matrix `M` based on `n`, and if you use the optional argument `'plot'` it will plot the decision rules of `M` using [`imagesc`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html).

```
function[M] = GenM(n, varargin)
% This function generates the binary matrix M.
% Inputs:
% n - number of input variables.
% Options:
% 'plot' - plot decision rules of M.

% Calculate necessary parameters.
[a, b, c, d, e] = CalcParams(n);

% Anonymous functions.
f1 = @(v, k) uint8(repmat(v, 1, k));
f2 = @(v, k) f1([v; ~v], k);
f3 = @(b, k) f2([false(1, b/(2*k)), ~false(1, b/(2*k))], k);

% Binary permutations of input variables (V) and decision (D).
Dec = 0:a-1; % Array: decimal representation of every state.
Bin = dec2bin(Dec); % Array: binary representation of every state.

% Preallocate matrix M.
M(length(Bin), d) = 0;

% Loop: input variables (V) and decision (D).
% Writes binary states in matrix M.
for i = 1:d
    M(:, i) = uint8(str2num(Bin(:, i)));
end

% Loop: decision rules.
% Writes binary permutations of decision rules (R) in matrix (M).
% Start with k = 1.
k = 1;
for i = 1:2:a
    M(i:(i + 1), c:e) = f3(b, k);
    k = k*2;
end

% Continue only if decision rules (R) are valid.
if(ValidDecRules(n, M))
    % Plot decision rules if 'plot' option is used.
    if(~isempty(varargin))
        if(any(strcmp(varargin, 'plot')))
            % Visualize decision rules as image.
            imagesc(M(:, c:e));
            title('Decision Rules (R)');
            colormap summer;
            axis off;
        end
    end
else
    % If decision rules are invalid, return empty output.
    M = [];
end

end
```

---

Finally I wrote a function called `EnumDecRules` which takes `n` and generates a table `T` very similar to the ones on the description of your question. The function also returns the binary matrix `M` that was used to generate `T`. And if you use the `'plot'` optional argument, it will plot the decision rules of `M` (like the `GenM` function).

The `EnumDecRules` function is the one that really answers your question because it has the behaviour that you are asking for.

```
function[T, M] = EnumDecRules(n, varargin)
% This function generates the table (T) with the results and also returns
% the binary matrix M that was used to generate T.
% Inputs:
% n - number of input variables.
% Options:
% 'plot' - plot decision rules of M.

% Calculate necessary parameters.
[a, ~, ~, d, e] = CalcParams(n);

% Generate the binary matrix M.
M = GenM(n, varargin{:});

if(~isempty(M))
    % Loop: variable names to diplay in table header.
    % Initialize indexes for numbering.
    Vi = 1; % Input variable numbering index.
    Ri = 1; % Decision rules numbering index.
    for i = 1:e
        if i <= n
            % Input variables.
            % Write V[Vi].
            Names{i} = ['V', sprintf('%d', Vi)];
            % Increase index.
            Vi = Vi + 1;
        elseif i == d
            % Decision.
            % Write D.
            Names{i} = 'D';
        elseif i > d
            % Decision rules.
            % Write R[Ri].
            Names{i} = ['R', sprintf('%d', Ri)];
            % Increase index.
            Ri = Ri + 1;
        end
    end

    % Generate table with results.
    T = array2table(M, ...
        'VariableNames', Names);

    % Modify decision column (D) of table.
    % Replace 0 with 'A'.
    % Replace 1 with 'B'.
    T.D = repmat({'A'; 'B'}, a/2, 1);
else
    % If M is empty, return empty output.
    T = [];
end

end
```

---

### Usage example:

> Make sure you save all the functions correctly in the same directory.

**Example 1:**

Call the `EnumDecRules` function to enumerate all possible decisions rules for `n = 1`:

```
[T, M] = EnumDecRules(1)
```

These are the outputs:

```
VALID decision rules
T = 
    V1     D     R1    R2    R3    R4
    __    ___    __    __    __    __
    0     'A'    0     0     1     1 
    0     'B'    1     1     0     0 
    1     'A'    0     1     0     1 
    1     'B'    1     0     1     0 
M =
     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0     1     0
```

**Example 2:**

Call the `EnumDecRules` function to enumerate all possible decisions rules for `n = 2` and also plot the decision rules:

```
[T, M] = EnumDecRules(2, 'plot')
```

These are the outputs:

```
VALID decision rules
T = 
    V1    V2     D     R1    R2    R3    R4    R5    R6    R7    R8    R9    R10    R11    R12    R13    R14    R15    R16
    __    __    ___    __    __    __    __    __    __    __    __    __    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___
    0     0     'A'    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1      1      1      1      1      1      1  
    0     0     'B'    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0  
    0     1     'A'    0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0      0      0      1      1      1      1  
    0     1     'B'    1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1      1      1      0      0      0      0  
    1     0     'A'    0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0      1      1      0      0      1      1  
    1     0     'B'    1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1      0      0      1      1      0      0  
    1     1     'A'    0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1      0      1      0      1      0      1  
    1     1     'B'    1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0      1      0      1      0      1      0  
M =
  Columns 1 through 9
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     1     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1
     1     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     0
  Columns 10 through 18
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
  Column 19
     1
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
     1
     0
```

And the plot:

[image: Plot of the decision rules of M for n = 2]

---

Since this type of algorithm grows so fast, using `EnumDecRules` or `GenM` for `n >= 5` can result in an out of memory error.

I really hope this will be helpful. If you have any questions about specific instructions of the code please leave a comment and I will be happy to answer them.

Comment: Great! I was wondering if the problem could be tackled with one or two lines of vectorized code. As the core of `GenM` shows this is not impossible. Thanks a lot for your detailed analysis and insightful comments!